# How is the Static method(main) able to grab hold of non static method(constructor) and execute it?

Tags: java, constructor, static, non-static

Seems like a very basic query but I was pondering how the static method main() below is able to execute a non static method(the constructor obviously) from it using the new keyword. Though I understand that **new** brings onto the table a few other things as well but how should I convince myself that this isn't an exception to the rule that static and non static methods can't using non static and static context respectively?

Below is the sample code:

```
public class ConstructorTest {

    ConstructorTest(String str)
    {
        System.out.println("Constructor Printing "+str);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConstructorTest cnst=new ConstructorTest("here");
    }

}
```

The above code actually prints --> **Constructor Printing here**

or *in other words executing the body of a Non static method from a Static method?*

Any plausible explanations are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) states that

> [...] Constructors are not members.

Therefore, there is no problem in calling them, since they are not bound to instances of your class. This would not make sense - hence, you cannot do the following:

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
Thing anotherThing = thing.Thing();
```

A constructor is **not** a method, so you cannot apply "method logic" to them.
In case you want to know more, the whole instantiation process is very well documented in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5). See *12.5. Creation of New Class Instances*.

Comment: So as per you not being a member of the class implies that static and non static context is not applicable for a constructor?

Comment: No, being a constructor implies that static and non static contexts are not applicable. If you read through the JLS, you will see that since they are neither members nor methods, the question of the context is irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah I meant constructors. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Actually constructor is compiled into the static method, this is how JVM internally creates instances of classes.

Comment: can you please provide any reference.

Comment: I read that in Thinking in Java from Bruce Eckel - unfortunately I don't have that book with me so I'll try to provide reference later.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing non-static code, but you are not doing it in a static context.

for instance:

```
public class C1{

  private int x;
  public String do(){  System.out.println("x = " + x);}

   public static void main(String[] args){
     do();
   }

}
```

This can not work, since do is an instance method, which might run code that is specific to the instance. So, how would the VM know which instance to use, or what value x should have?

Now, to first use a constructor, which is possible from any context:

```
public class C1{

  private int x;
  public String do(){  System.out.println("x = " + x);}

   public static void main(String[] args){
     C1 t = new C1();
     t.do();
   }

}
```

Here, even though you are calling the method from within a static method, you are using it through an instance, so not in a static context.

Comment: op isnt talking about instance method but calling constructor itself.

Comment: the op has edited his question since I posted. The first question was: how come I can call the non-static constructor in a static method.

Comment: My question how can you simply even call C1() as it is a constructor and it is non static?

Answer (score 1):

ConstructorTest is not a method.
its an constructor,and you can use the constructor for initialize class property.
you can also initialize the static variable from the constructor like that :-

```
public class XYZ 
{
static int i=0;

public XYZ() {
    i=1;//not an compile time error
}

public static void doSome(){}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

On a formal language level you should read the line

```
ConstructorTest cnst = new ConstructorTest("here")
```

as a [class instance creation expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9). As a matter of fact, *this is not a call to a constructor* or any other method.

The instance creation does many steps, like allocating memory for the new object, initializing the fields, calling constructors and initializer blocks. See [JLS §12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) for a detailed step-by-step description. Thus being said, the constructor invocation is only a part of the instance creation.

Additionally, you might see constructors as being static parts of the class. In fact, *constructor declaration are not members* (see [JLS §8.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8)) and thus they are not overridable (as static methods also). Beware: This is only half true. When being inside the constructor you already have the instance created, and you are able to call other instance methods and/or access instance fields.